# how to disable userland-proxy for docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

How to disable "userland-proxy" so that when using "docker-compose" it is disabled.

I tried running *docker-compose up --userland-proxy=false* but no luck.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Disabling the Userland proxy is a global configuration, configured at the daemon level. You cannot change this configuration from the client, and thus not from docker compose.

To disable the proxy, you need to change the daemon configuration (see the [`dockerd reference`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/67fdf574d5acd6ddccb6ece0ffe0ace1c1608712/docs/reference/commandline/dockerd.md). You can do so following the steps below (these steps should be done on the host that the *daemon* runs);

Create a file named `/etc/docker/daemon.json` if it does not exist, and add the `"userland-proxy": false` setting. The `daemon.json` file should be valid JSON; if this is the only configuration in that file, it should look like;

```
{
    "userland-proxy": false
}
```

After saving the file, restart the daemon using (if your host uses `systemd`);

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

> **Note**: On Docker for Mac and Docker for Windows, the userland-proxy cannot be disabled, as it is an essential part of the networking (i.e. it allows connections to `localhost` to be forwarded to the containers)

Comment: Thanks for the note on Mac and Windows. That's a big shame. Takes forever to open a lot of ports..