# Opening Ports from Docker on buildroot system

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi3, buildroot

I just set up buildroot on my RPi3 with docker. It boots up fine and docker also works, but when I try to run a container (e.g. portainer) that need to open a port, it fails with

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint portainer (b6130d6ee0d30f867ff0e99349db1567389b18e9f42ca35718e0a5aefcb3976d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp [::]:9443: bind: address already in use.
```

It doesn't matter which port I try, it always fails.
doing a `netstat | grep 9443` doesn't give any output, which should mean that ther is no other process using this port.

Any recommendations on how to fix this?

EDIT 1: my buildroot version is 2021.08-rc3 and my config can be found in this pastebin
https://pastebin.com/ttWZ6PpY

I am trying out if the same thing happens on buildroot 2021.08.

EDIT 2: I switched to buildroot 2021.08 and changed as little as possible, so only `make raspberrypi3_64_defconfig`, changing to glibc as C library, enabling docker-cli, docker-compose, docker-engine, ntp (with ntpd) and openssh as well as setting timezone, rootpassword and filesystem image size to 512M, then flashing the image and extending the root partition. After booting up I directly startet a mimimal container like in the unit test with `docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 busybox:latest /bin/true`, but I still get the same error.

The new config can be found here:  https://pastebin.com/hrTKf26B

EDIT 3: I also tried the 32bit-version (so `make raspberrypi3_defconfig` in the beginning), but that results in the same error when trying to start a docker container.

EDIT 4: I also tried going back to buildroot LTS (2021.02.5) and installing dbus, but both didn't help.

Comment: If it helps: Docker version is 20.10.7

Comment: Run `docker ps -a` to see if you have any exited containers

Comment: no, there are not

Comment: Please provide more details, E.G. what Buildroot version, what is your Buildroot configuration and have you made any local changes? We have a unit test for docker / docker-compose, so it would be surprising if this isn't working: https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/support/testing/tests/package/test_docker_compose.py

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue following this [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413816/how-to-disable-userland-proxy-for-docker-compose) which provides a solution to disable `userland-proxy` for docker-compose.

I struggled with this the whole day. The key was the part of the error message that says `'Error starting userland proxy'`.

I'm also in an RPi3 but with Buildroot 2021.02.8. I've had this selection related to docker on the menuconfig:

```
[*] docker-cli
[ ]   build static client
[*] docker-compose
-*- docker-containerd
[ ]   btrfs snapshot driver
[*] docker-engine 
... (rest unselected)
-*- docker-proxy
```